# wrighting many scss files into one minified css

Tags: css, macos, sass, node-sass

I have four files:

- scss/bootstrap-grid.scss
- scss/bootstrap-reboot.scss
- scss/bootstrap-utilities.scss
- scss/bootstrap.scss

And out of these files I need 3 - public/css/styles.css styles.css.map and styles.min.css

Where min.css is minified file and map is map file, can I do in in one script command using node sass? I'm using macOS

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely do that.

The only thing you need to do is name all of your SCSS files starting with an underscore.

Then you need to make style.scss, import the othe SCSS files into it, then compile it.

The underscore as the first character of the file name tells the compiler that the file is a partial and shouldn’t be compiled.

It gets compiled by being imported.

Assuming that you have `style.scss` in the same folder as the partial files, this is all you would need in `style.scss`

```
   @import "_bootstrap-grid";
   @import "_bootstrap-reboot";
   @import "_bootstrap-utilities";
   @import "_bootstrap";
```

Comment: thanks @DanMullin but how would the script declaration would look like?

Comment: @Seven I updated the answer with what the style.scss file needs to contain

Comment: but I mean like in package.json :) so that I get styles.css, styles.min.css and styles.map.css